# The window detects scrolling inexplicably

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I have a fairly simple function that detects a window scroll. Fires a timeout event (500ms) when the user stops scrolling. This ends then listener and timeout. I then animate(GSAP) the window to a certain point. Once the animation is complete, the listener is fired up again. Sometimes... a scroll is detected again, so the whole function is fired twice. Please look into console to see this happening.

code here:

```
var timeout;
var onScroll = function() {
  console.log('scrolling...');
  if(timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('done scrolling... stop listening...');
    $(window).off( "scroll", onScroll);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;

    // aniamte scroll
    console.log('start animating scroll...');
    TweenMax.to($(window), 0.1, {scrollTo:{y:500}, onComplete:function(){
      $(window).on( "scroll", onScroll);
      console.log('done animating scroll. Start litening again.');
    }});

  }, 500);
}
$(window).on( "scroll", onScroll);
```

example: http://codepen.io/rgbjoy/pen/RGVLBK?editors=0011

How is this happening? Should I be asking quantum theorist?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your onComplete function is getting called before the scrollTo tween is finished.

I changed the console log statement in onScroll to this:

```
console.log('scrolling to ' + window.pageYOffset );
```

Then I saw this in the log:

```
"scrolling to 341"
"scrolling to 340"
"scrolling to 338"
"done scrolling... stop listening..."
"start animating scroll..."
"done animating scroll. Start litening again."
"scrolling to 500"
"done scrolling... stop listening..."
"start animating scroll..."
"done animating scroll. Start litening again."
```

So that 'Scrolling to 500' seems to come from the tween finishing after the onComplete method gets called.

I'm not sure what the solution to this is, since it seems like a bug in TweenMax.

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper on this. This maybe a bug in the GSAP plugin. I was banging my head on it forever. I like to use the GSAP plugin because I use it a lot for other animations. The scrollTo plugin sounded great and easy to use...